# Will everything from my previous character from Gta 5 online go to my new one?

Tags: ps4, grand-theft-auto-online

I want a fresh start because I messed on my first character. I have the special edition so I get few extra stuff. I want a fresh start like just making your character.

Will everything save from my 1st character to my 2nd? Like money bank money houses cars etc?

Answer (score 1):

The only thing that is shared between characters is the Bank Account, so everything else will be lost if has already been claimed (aka purchased for free).